# Realtime Muxing of videos

Tags: go, ffmpeg, muxer

My problem basically comes from me having 2 different streams for videoplayback and having to mux them realtime in memory. One for video, and another for audio.

My goal is to create a proxy which can mux 2 different webm streams from their URLs, while supporting range requests (requires knowing the encoded file size). Would this be possible?

This is how I mux the audio and video streams manually using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm -i audio.webm -c copy output.webm
```

But, this requires me to download the video fully to process it, which I don't want to do unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for this to work in go you can look into

```
github.com/at-wat/ebml-go/webm
```

This provides a `BlockWriter` interface to write to `webm` file using buffers; You can see the test file to checkout how to use it

https://github.com/at-wat/ebml-go

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [ffmpeg pipes](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe).

Also since you have tagged go - i'm assuming you will use os/exec - in which case also checkout [Cmd.ExtraFiles](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd). This lets you use additional [pipes(files)](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe) beyond just the standard 0, 1 and 2.

So let's say you have a stream for video and one for audio piping to **3** and **4** respectively. The ffmpeg bit of your command becomes:

ffmpeg -i pipe:3 -i pipe:4 -c copy output.webm

Comment: I see, I wanted to use some kind of ffmpeg bindings ideally, but I'll see if I can get this to work. Also, how would handling the range requests work? That's something I can't figure out how to do with the documentation.